# need to login to sudo terminal without asking for a password

Tags: linux, terminal, sudo

hi i don't have access to my desktop how can i run sudo terminal without logging in.

i do have my correct password but it wont work. but during logon it tells me my home directory is set to .. but it is not there .

I've already tried Ctrl+alt+F1 asks me for my password witch then wont accept

what should i do ?

the command i want to type is : `sudo chown root /home/user/`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question clearly. let me try to re-phrase. You are locked out of your desktop because you have forgotten your password, right? Do you by any chance know the password for `root`? if so, just login using that and change your password.

If you do not remember that, one of the ways (if you have access to the computer, which I assume you have), then reboot the PC using a rescue CD/USB stick and modify the password.

See: http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Resetting-Passwords-with-SystemRescueCd